# TLS handshake failed: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error calling hello

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mongodb-atlas

Before i post this question i have been struggling to make this work for more than a week anyway let start.
I have been trying to deploy my full stack application that is made up with laravel api angular and mongodb atlas, i sat up my database on mongodb atlas and and i deployed my angular application in S3 aws, and my laravel api in elastic beanstalk service aws,i have successfully deployed my angular and laravel, now when i try to test a simple api call that will recover list of todos in my mongodb atlas database i get this **Error**:
`` No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [TLS handshake failed: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error calling hello on 'ac-qvcir0t-shard-00-01.zgs6u4e.mongodb.net:27017'] [TLS handshake failed: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error calling hello on 'ac-qvcir0t-shard-00-02.zgs6u4e.mongodb.net:27017'] [TLS handshake failed: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error calling hello on 'ac-qvcir0t-shard-00-00.zgs6u4e.mongodb.net:27017'] `` 
here is a screenshot of the error:
[screenshot of laravel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/442Gp.jpg)
now i have tried to create a new **VPC** in my aws to peer it with mongodb atlas here is a screen shot of the vpc peering that i did :
[screenshot of VPC peering between aws and mongodb atlas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emfPF.png)

and of course i have used this VPC that has been peered in my elastic beanstalk environment but still getting the same error, i would appreciate for some help or at least an explanation of what is happening im a student that trying to learn thanks ♥

also i have tried to install **mongodb shell** on my ec2 instance to see if i can connect to my mongodb atlas through my ec2 instance but i couldn't install the package here is a screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYHZG.png)
or here is the full error:

```
[root@ip-172-31-45-73 ~]# sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
Amazon Linux 2023 repository                                                                                  38 MB/s |  17 MB     00:00    
Amazon Linux 2023 Kernel Livepatch repository                                                                542 kB/s | 160 kB     00:00    
MongoDB Repository                                                                                           166 kB/s |  63 kB     00:00    
MongoDB Repository                                                                                           110 kB/s |  58 kB     00:00    
MongoDB Repository                                                                                            71 kB/s |  32 kB     00:00    
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.0-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.10-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.11-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.12-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.13-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.14-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.15-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.16-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.17-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.18-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.19-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the 

.............

  - package mongodb-org-4.4.5-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-shell = 4.4.5, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.6-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-shell = 4.4.6, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.7-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-shell = 4.4.7, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.8-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-shell = 4.4.8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.9-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-shell = 4.4.9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.1-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.1-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.10-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.10-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.10-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.10-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.10-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.11-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.11-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.11-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.11-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.11-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.12-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.12-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.12-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.12-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.12-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.13-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.13-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.13-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.13-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.13-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.14-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.14-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.14-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.14-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.14-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.15-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.15-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.15-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.15-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.15-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.16-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.16-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.16-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.16-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.16-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.17-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.17-
........
1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.9-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.9-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-5.0.9-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.0-1.amzn2.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.1-1.amzn2.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.10-1.amzn2.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.2-1.amzn2.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.3-1.amzn2.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.4-1.amzn2.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.5-1.amzn2.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.6-1.amzn2.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.7-1.amzn2.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.8-1.amzn2.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.9-1.amzn2.aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
[root@ip-172-31-45-73 ~]#
```

i have tried with mongodb shell version 4.4 and 5.0 and 6.0 and still same error here are the steps that i used to install the shell :

**sudo yum clean metadata**

**sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-6.0.repo**
Copy code
**[mongodb-org-6.0]
name=MongoDB Repository

baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2/mongodb-org/6.0/aarch64/

gpgcheck=1

enabled=1

gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc**
Save and exit the file.
install MongoDB 6.0:
**sudo yum install -y mongodb-org**